# What are context aware variables?

Tags: variables, go

I heard someone talking about how Go has a good implementation of "context aware variables" when working with HTML. What are they and how do they work?

I'm guessing since it was related to security that it's some sort of variable that knows if it has been sanitized or not. Is it something like a class called `unsanitizedString` where it automatically sanitizes the contents when casting to a normal string?

Comment: After a little more research I saw [this](http://www.veracode.com/blog/2013/12/golangs-context-aware-html-templates), although I still don't understand exactly what it's doing.

Comment: To get background on context-aware HTML templating, read: http://js-quasis-libraries-and-repl.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/safetemplate.html#problem_definition and http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2009/03/reducing-xss-by-way-of-automatic.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [html/template](http://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package is context aware.

> This package understands HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and URIs. It adds sanitizing functions to each simple action pipeline

So if you have variable `Foo` that contains `<script>alert('you have been pwned')</script>` and you print it inside an html element `<p>{{.Foo}}</p>` Foo will be properly escaped to avoid script injection.

When using `html/template` you have to add explicet types to your variables if you want to override when escaping should happen.

Here is an [example](http://play.golang.org/p/BjRNvEJwzZ)